# I don't want to apply styles to my button

Tags: css

I want to put a button without style inside a big page that use several CSS. So, I don't want to apply these styles to my button.

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific. Post the css of what you are trying to do. What isn't working and how likely do you want it work ?

Comment: Then don't apply the styles to the button. Can you post your CSS/HTML?

Comment: @Blender: `Then don't apply the styles to the button.` Clearly, that's his entire question. He's asking how to nullify all the other styles already being applied to his button. For example, if he uses something like the Twitter Bootstrap CSS framework, his buttons will already have a style. He's asking how to eliminate all applied CSS rules on a specific element.

Comment: @Mahesh Thanks for your attention. I have no experience with CSS and maybe the answer is evident but I don't know how to do it. My question is general too. Why can I have a button inside a table with several styles, and I don't want to apply the styles to my button. I just want to have it without style even if I put it in my page with many things. Thanks again :)

Comment: @SergioTapia: we'll never know, sadly. If the OP wrote his/her own CSS, then the scope might be too large and it should be reduced. If not, then my solution below might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a CSS class to your button and override all of the rules already being applied to it by other CSS rules.

```
<input class="blandbutton" />

.blandbutton {
    /* Override rules already set to the button */
    /* If you have a CSS rule that gives it a border of 1px solid cyan,
       this will cause any element with the blandbutton class to use THIS 
       as it's more specific. */

    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your button, and override the styles:

```
<input class="mybutton" />

.mybutton
{
background:none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Without *any* code or context, the most I can do is link you to the [YUI Contextual CSS Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) stylesheet.

Just include it as a stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset-context/cssreset-context-min.css">
```

And add this class to your element:

```
 class="yui3-cssreset"
```

Comment: It just changes the colour. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Can you give us your HTML and CSS? Nobody can help you without those pieces of information.

Comment: The web site is big, so I will try by myself. You information is useful. Thank you! :)

Comment: What do you mean by `button`. Like a normal `<input type="button" />`? Are you asking how to remove *all* (even the OS-default) styles on the button so it's just a box?

Comment: Yes, button is a <input type="button" />. I want that it seems like a "normal" button without apply the style. I don't want to remove the OS-default. Thanks :)